# Fan Does Not Work! - LIFEBOOK AH532

Tags: lubuntu, overheating, fan

I've problem with my laptop fan in Lubuntu 14.04 64bit.
(model: Fujitsu LIFEBOOK AH532) [Datasheet](http://globalsp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/ds-LIFEBOOK-AH532.pdf)

**Fan does not work! :-(**
How can I fix it? (Or how can I force enable fan?)

### Some of my tries:

```
$ sudo sensors # After sensors-detect

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +59.0°C  (crit = +84.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +61.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +60.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
```

**61°C!** also CPU is not busy.

```
$ sudo pwmconfig

# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

```
$ sudo fancontrol

Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the fan has just died?

Comment: No! In Windows 8.1 I have not any problem.

Comment: maybe some option about fan speed/control in bios?

Comment: BIOS of AH532 has 2 modes for fan: Silent and Normal and my laptop is in normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

add at the end: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="!Windows 2012""`

Comment: Thanks! I think this works! **Fan is working.**

But `sensors` and `pwmconfig` has not any change yet! :(

**How can I check the fan status/RPM?**

Comment: Please explain about reason of this solution? why adding `acpi_osi="!Windows 2012" solves this problem?

Comment: By adding that line, you make the bios believe that your system is windows 8 instead of linux. Many bios vendors don't support officialy linux acpi, and for so the linux kernel offers this "emulation" method to bypass the limitations. I'm sorry if I don't make much sense, I'm not an expert. About the sensors. If they didn't work with acpi=linux(default) I don't think there's going to be a way to make them work now. But you could try upgrading the bios, maybe the manufacturer added support.

Comment: After browsing through the forums, people suggest trying other acpi modes: acpi_osi="!Windows 2006"  acpi_osi="Windows 2006"  acpi_osi="Linux"  acpi_osi="Windows 2001 SP2"